# How to Compare Mortality Rates Among 5 Groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing

What statistical test would I use to compare differences in mortality among 5 independent groups? I know chi square can be used for comparing 2 groups.

Comment: You can use the chi-squared with >2 groups.

Comment: However, chi-square tests as usually encountered deal with counted categories. Mortality rates sound like rates per thousand population, or some such.

Comment: Can you clarify what form of data you have?

Answer (score 1):

You want to see whether the distribution in frequencies among the five groups is consistent with a discrete uniform distribution (null hypothesis) or they are instead different enough to reject the null. To do so, you can use a goodness-of-fit test chi squared test.

If you are using R, you can do something like this:

```
group_mortality  <- c(15, 21, 11, 09, 22)
expected_freq    <- rep(1/5,5)
(ch_sq <- chisq.test(group_mortality, p= expected_freq))

Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  group_mortality
X-squared = 8.6667, df = 4, p-value = 0.06999
```

In a case like this the $\chi^2$ value wouldn't be extreme enough to reject the null with a risk alpha of $<5\%$.